# Generate automatic number by selecting an option

Tags: javascript, html

The code that generates my number:

```
<input type="radio" class="alege" name="uni_code_type" id="alegeT" value="T" onclick="getUniCode()"> 
<label for="alegeT" class="control-label">T</label> 

<input type="radio" class="alege" name="uni_code_type" id="alegeP" value="P" onclick="getUniCode()"> 
<label for="alegeP" class="control-label">P</label>

<input id="uni_code" name="uni_code" type="text" class="form-control">
```

and here is the corresponding JS:

```
 var seq = 0;
        // var d = new Date();
```

```
    var dateObj = new Date();
    var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
    var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
    var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
    newdate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;

    function getUniCode() {
      // Increment the value
      seq += 1

      // The string value that will be displayed
      var value = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"].alege:checked').value;

      // If sequence is less than 10, prefix with 000
      if (seq < 10) {
        value += '00' + seq + "-" + newdate;
      }
      // If sequence is less than 100, prefix with 00
      else if (seq < 100) {
        value += '0' + seq + "-" + newdate;
      }
      // If sequence is less than 1000, prefix with 0
      else if (seq < 1000) {
        value += '' + seq + "-" + newdate;;
      }
      // Otherwise, just use the value directly
      else {
        value += seq;
      }


      // Display the formatted value (ie prefixed with 0's)
      document.getElementById("uni_code").value = value;

    }
```

For now, if I select T, it generates a code like T001-6 / 4/2020 and if I select P and then I select T, this appears: P002-6 / 4/2020. I would like it after I press T and then press P to appear also at P all from 1 not from the number generated when I press T! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I solve it thanks hehe :D ` var seq = 0;
        // var d = new Date();

```
    var dateObj = new Date();
    var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
    var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
    var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
    newdate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;

    function getUniCode() {
      // Increment the value
      seq += 1

      // The string value that will be displayed
      var value = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"].alege:checked').value;

      // If sequence is less than 10, prefix with 000
      if (seq < 10) {
        value += '00' + seq + "-" + newdate;
      }
      // If sequence is less than 100, prefix with 00
      else if (seq < 100) {
        value += '0' + seq + "-" + newdate;
      }
      // If sequence is less than 1000, prefix with 0
      else if (seq < 1000) {
        value += '' + seq + "-" + newdate;;
      }
      // Otherwise, just use the value directly
      else {
        value += seq;
      }


      // Display the formatted value (ie prefixed with 0's)
      document.getElementById("uni_code").value = value;

    }
```

//

var seqe = 0;
        // var d = new Date();

```
    var dateObj = new Date();
    var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
    var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
    var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
    newdate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;

    function getUniCodee() {
      // Increment the value
      seqe += 1

      // The string value that will be displayed
      var value = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"].alege:checked').value;

      // If sequence is less than 10, prefix with 000
      if (seqe < 10) {
        value += '00' + seqe + "-" + newdate;
      }
      // If sequence is less than 100, prefix with 00
      else if (seqe < 100) {
        value += '0' + seqe + "-" + newdate;
      }
      // If sequence is less than 1000, prefix with 0
      else if (seqe < 1000) {
        value += '' + seqe + "-" + newdate;;
      }
      // Otherwise, just use the value directly
      else {
        value += seqe;
      }


      // Display the formatted value (ie prefixed with 0's)
      document.getElementById("uni_code").value = value;

    }`
```

i did this and now it works as i want :D